# Shrink code chunks in a documentation

Tags: listings, code

i'm making a documentation of a system, and i have a lot of code chunks that i want to explain, but some of them are too long. My questions if there are some way to automatically shrink those too big chunks to a fixed number of lines, let say N+3 where 3 are the 3 dotted lines, something like

```
 codeline1
 codeline2
 .
 .
 .
 codelineN
```

i'm actually using listings to typeset those code chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `linerange` setting to limit the number of lines in the code that you are displaying.

Comment: Nice! that helps a lot, now i need to write the three dotted vertical lines, do you know how?